# Security of Lindner-Peikert parameters for lwe

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto, lwe

From [Regev's paper](https://www.cims.nyu.edu/~regev/papers/qcrypto.pdf) in 2005, we know that for applying worst-case to average-case reduction to an lwe cryptosystem, one should use error distributions with standard deviation $s$ bigger than $2\sqrt{n}$. Why this condition is not regarded by [Lindner & Peikert](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/613.pdf) parameters (e.g. n=128 & s=6.77)?

Comment: Isn't it just for efficiency reasons? Even without a worst-case to average-case reduction, you can have parameters for which no attack is known, hence it is natural to set up for such parameters to get a practical scheme.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is for efficiency reasons or not?!

Comment: In the ring-based variant of LWE, we know that the hypotheses of the worst-case hardness theorem are almost minimal ones which provide security guarantees. Isn't it true for LWE problem?

Comment: Do you have a link to the Lindner & Peikert article you're referencing?  There was a period where lattice crypto was considered too inefficient for practical, large-scale use so the changes could have been made for optimization (as has been pointed out).

Comment: @hamidreza On the contrary, we don't know that.  There's still a sizable gap between the hypotheses of the worst-case hardness theorems and the best known attacks for, say, cyclotomic rings.  (The gap is even larger in the regime where only a few Ring-LWE samples are provided to the attacker, which is the case for basic RLWE encryption.)

Comment: @GeoffroyCouteau is correct -- more specifically, it's to reduce the size of the modulus $q$ and thereby the sizes of the public keys and ciphertexts.

Comment: @ChrisPeikert It's surprising. You mean that many LWE-based cryptosystems have not worst-case to average-case security reductions (because of efficiency) and are just based on the hardness of LWE. So, why the lattice community is always proud of this strong security property (regardless of whether use it or not)?!

Comment: @hamidreza It's a remarkable and unique property that other problems used in crypto don't seem to have. And it helps us identify the "right" average-case problems, like LWE, to use and study, which is very nontrivial for lattices. (Many ad-hoc problems have turned out to be fundamentally broken.)